# OpenShift - Get project URL using oc get project

Tags: openshift

I am dealing with a deployment of Jenkins across multiple OCP versions and clusters. OCP 3 and 4 have different URL schemes for projects so I am looking for a uniform way to get the URL to the web console of a particular project using the `oc` tool, for example:

```sh
oc get project abcxyz -o go-template --template '{{.metadata.annotations.url}}`
```

or something like that.

Comment: What do you mean by "URL to a particular project"? The `Routes` within a project (`oc get routes`)? A certain annotation on the project? Can you clarify that in the question?

Comment: The URL to the web console of the project. I have clarified the question